# Large performance variance with Javascript object instantiation size & methods

Tags: javascript, performance, object, instantiation, microbenchmark

I have noticed a significant performance difference among the various object instantiation methods. Furthermore, it seems as though the size of the object (i.e. # of properties) matters greatly sometimes.

Can anyone shed some light on the results of the following jsperf?
http://jsperf.com/objects-w-more-less-8-properties/5

```
var thisobj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8}
```

This seems to be hands down the fasted way to create a new object

```
var thisobj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9}
```

This is vastly slower... the only difference being the 9th value

```
var thisobj = new objsm(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

AND

```
var thisobj = new objlg(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Don't differ that much from each other (about as much you would expect), but they still differ greatly from the 'dynamically' defined object above. Their objects are defined here:

```
    var objsm = function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) {
    this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d; this.e = e; this.f = f; this.g = g; this.h = h;}

var objlg = function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) {
this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d; this.e = e; this.f = f; this.g = g; this.h = h; this.i = i; }
```

---

Why is "`var thisobj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8}`" so superior?

Comment: fyi, In Chrome, the difference is even more exaggerated.

Comment: The difference is quite small on Firefox 42

Comment: It could be related to when JIT comes in picture

Comment: I would assume it has to do with caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance differences like this often are not due to the *language* javascript but due to the *implementation* of that language.

Other factors, such as heap occupancy (and thus resulting GC costs) can also affect performance.

Since there are multiple implementations out there - which are constantly evolving - and browsers don't have the habit of spitting out the generated assembly there is no general answer.

For example on FF 45 I'm getting pretty much identical performance for all four cases:

[image: FF45 benchmark run]

Presumably the JIT compilers are  simply smart enough to perform dead code elimination here so we're essentially benchmarking an empty loop. In other words this result shows how well compilers optimize and not the cost of object allocations.

[Making the objects escape](http://jsperf.com/objects-w-more-less-8-properties/7) into the global scope yields the following results, which are about what one would expect:

[image]

Note that a sufficiently advanced compiler™ could probably eliminate all but the last allocation from the loop by observing that they all write to the same variable without reads between iterations.

So future browser versions might "break" this benchmark again.

Microbenchmarks are tricky business.

Comment: Right, the first FF results are certainly due to some 'advanced' browser work effectively ignoring the bulk of the instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the hashmap-based form is executed *natively*, while the constructor-based form executes a function which needs to be *interpreted*. I suppose this interpretation effort causes the difference of performances.

And what about the 8-properties threshold? A HashMap needs to be pre-sized with a size *over the maximum number of values it should contain* (if not, accesing times will increase). If some browser vendor has chosen a low value (8-10 by example), every attempt to store more than 8 items will reduce performance.

However, the **main** correlation in the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/objects-w-more-less-8-properties/5) you mention it is not over the test, but over the browser: Every browser shows quite similar results in all tests, which is quite plausible.